# Unable to use data sent back from my Json file to the web page

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json file which i can return a result from. The problem i am having is that i cannot get the results back onto the page (so to speak). I think it is to do with the format of the Json which i cannot control and looks like this:

```
[
[
    {
        "Key": "AddressLine1",
        "Value": "Acacia Avenue"
    },
    {
        "Key": "AddressLine2",
        "Value": "secondlineofaddress"
    },
    {
        "Key": "City",
        "Value": "someCity"
    },
    {
        "Key": "HouseNameOrNumber",
        "Value": "2"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Postcode",
        "Value": "sdlfkjhsdljkf"
    }
]
```

]

The javascript looks like this

```
    $('#addressFinder').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value01 = $("#Address_HouseNameOrNumber").val();
    var value02 = $("#Address_Postcode").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/addresstomyjSON/AddressSearch',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            houseNo: value01,
            postCode: value02
        },
        success: function (data) {


            var items = [];

            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
            });

            $('<ul/>', {
                'class': 'my-new-list',
                html: items.join('')
            }).appendTo('#body');

    });
});
```

So i am trying to write out the address as an list the results i get fromt he current code is a single li tag with an ID of 0 and then [object Object] repeated 5 times. I think it is to do with how i am trying to set the variable in the success functions but i am unsure what the corrrect syntax to use is. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its an array in an array, so try doing a `$.each(data[0], ...`

Edit: more

```
$.each(data[0], function () {
    items.push('<li id="' + this.Key + '">' + this.Value + '</li>');
});
```